# Prove or disprove: Given signature and structures, isomorphism... Then the structure is unique

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

> Prove or disprove: Let $\Sigma = (U; f_1,..,f_n)$ be a signature, let
>   $S,R$ be $\Sigma-$structures, let $S$ be unique. Let $\phi: U_S
> \rightarrow U_R$ be an isomorphism. Then $R$ is unique.

I really don't know how to prove this well and not sure if I got it correctly?

So if we assume that $S$ is unique and $R$ is unique, then they are abstractly the same in that one is a copy of the other in the sense that there is a one one correspondence with gives homomorphisms both ways between $R$ and $S$ which means that both structures are isomorphic. Task assumed that we have the isomorphism $\phi: U_S \rightarrow U_R$ and thus $R$ is really unique and the statement is true...?

Comment: What does it mean to say a structure is unique?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Say we have the structure $S=(U_1,..,U_n; g_1,..,g_m)$ and let $u \in U_1 \cup .. \cup U_n$. Then $u$ is unique if $u$ is generated exactly in one kind. And $S$ is unique if every generated $u \in U_1 \cup .. \cup U_n$ is unique. In case the meaning of "generated" is unknown: $u$ is generated in $S$, if $u=g_i$ for an $i$ or $u=g_i(u_1,..,u_n)$ for an $i$ and $u_1,..,u_n$ are generated.

Comment: And what does it mean for an element to be generated exactly in one kind? This seems like very unusual use of terminology. What's the source of this question / these definitions?